# jquery children first remove class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a web page that has a few elements hidden on load here is the sections html layout[image]
As you can see their is a button that on click i need to remove the hidden class on the next child here is the jquery code.

```
$(document).on('click', '#find-button', function (e) {
 $('#find-data').children().first('.hidden').removeClass('hidden');
});
```

not sure what is happening but the code does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic isn't quite right.

`first()` returns the very first element in the collection so as written you would have the first child.

Use the `.hidden` selector on `children()` instead to filter only the ones with that class, and get `first()` of that reduced set

Change to

```
$('#find-data').children('.hidden').first().removeClass('hidden');
```